# xpath to fetch child items with the same tag name as parent

Tags: xml, xpath

My requirement is to fetch the value of attributes of child tags which have the same name parent.
Following is the XML structure like:

```
<A>
    <B ID="id">
        <B parentID="id" .. other attributes>
        <B parentID="id" .. other attributes>
        <B parentID="id" .. other attributes>
        <B parentID="id" .. other attributes>
    </B>
</A>
```

I am expecting to fetch the attribute values of all childs B tags under parent B tag.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it.

xpath should be:
`A/B/B/*[@parent_Id="id"]/@id`

Comment: That might give the right answer for this particular test document but it bears very little relationship to the stated requirement. Do you have any other test cases?

Answer (score 0):

An XPath to return all elements having the same name as their parent element is

```
//*[name()=name(..)]
```